# Contact Form 7 not sending emails- no confirmation, no error

Tags: forms, email, plugin-contact-form-7, phpmailer

[Live site.](http://frshstudio.com)

I've noticed that Contact Form 7 recently stopped working, despite my not having touched any of the settings. What's odd is that I receive neither a confirmation nor an error message; I click "send" and nothing happens. This problem persists across FF, Safari, and Chrome.

I read in other, older threads that it could be something to do with SMTP settings, but as the threads were 2 years old, most of the work-around plugins they suggested are no longer an option. I also found a [patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/20970/20970.patch) that was intended to address a problem similar to what I'm experiencing, but the patch has made no difference in my situation.

Any ideas?

Once the problem is fixed.. is there any way for me to obtain the lost email? I use the form for my business site and have undoubtedly lost leads because of this..

WP 3.4.2
CF7 3.3.1

ETA: [More info here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-not-sending-emails-no-confirmation-no-error?replies=19#post-3452729).

Comment: Talk to your web host. Most likely they have changed something that is messing up your SMTP settings.

Comment: Hey user1255049 do you have any more issues that I can help you with? I think my answer down low will provide the right answer. Please consider to accept it and or also reward me the bounty. If you need more help let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked your site. There is **a javascript error** when you submit the form. It looks like the **issue is caused by the plugin wp-super-heatmap**.

Disable that and try it again! If that is not it, start disabling one plugin at a time. I am certain that another plugin causes this issue, and I am pretty sure it is **wp-super-heatmap**!

Comment: Interesting. Disabling the plugin enabled CF7 to function in that I could click send and see indicator that it was trying to send, however I now have this message:

Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the Contact Form 7 FAQ http://contactform7.com/faq/#I_get_an_error_message_with_a_red_border_So_how_can_I_solve_this
**After submitting the form, I get an error message stating “Failed to send your message”. What is wrong?**

Comment: I am not sure where you are hosted ... however this link might help -> http://angstrey.com/index.php/2009/04/22/how-to-send-e-mail-with-wordpress-from-godaddy-windows-hosting/ also from the CF7 FAQ list.  It is kind of hard to tell what is wrong when it goes to the backend. CF7 however is now fully functional again and actually gives you feedback. That is good!

Comment: The link mentioned in my last comment opts for WP-Mail-SMTP plugin that might get you more details on your mail problem...

Comment: Ok I just checked, you are actually on godaddy, so that link will actually tell you exactly what is wrong with it!

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts with this; I followed both posts to a T and still get that pesky red error!

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are using CF7, then do please use the [a CF7 to DB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) Extension, which ensures that all the Contact Form data is also saved in a database which you can access and export via the WP admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your email data is lost since the email was never sent. This could be an issue with your hosting/server php settings as well.

If all of a sudden emails do not come in any more I would not blame the plugin but the underlying infrastructure that used to make the system work. Has anything changed in your hosting? Have you tried different email addresses to receive emails from cf7?

Comment: That's what I initially thought, too. I checked with my host and nothing changed with my service nor did they see any email activity. I've tried both @ mydomain.com and @ gmail.com email address with no luck.